# Retriving lastModifiedByName and lastModifiedDate programatically

Tags: metadata-api

I can use workbench to get see the  `lastModifiedByName` and `lastModifiedDate` via the  `Metadata Types & Components` options under 'info' in `workbench`. Expanding each components, i see that there is `fileName` option, that i can use to select a file.

I want to get the two information for the list of files in a given `package.xml` programatically. Any thought on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Under **Metadata Types & Components** Workbench is displaying the [FileProperties](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_retrieveresult.htm#retrieveresult_fileproperties_title) that get returned by a [ListMetadataQuery](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_listmetadataquery.htm).

For instance, if I set the `ListMetadataQuery.type` to `ApexClass` I get a result back that includes the `lastModifiedByName` and `lastModifiedDate` for each ApexClass in the Org.